# How open file from list on servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need open for read .xml file from list. How i can do it? I try write servlet, but not sure how is working with list
And what i should write in web.xml and logs.jsp?
Please help me! Thank you

```
//servlet for open for read file
package Logs;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/file")
public class OpenFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        File[] files = new File("C:\\DevPrograms\\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\\webapps\\Report\\Logs").listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("C:\\DevPrograms\\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\\webapps\\Report\\Logs" + files[i]));
            req.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("\\" + file);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("\\" + file).forward(req, resp);
        }

    }
}
```

"but if i click file, tomcat show me error 500. Row 17, because i'm put this class without first two rows (package Logs and space)"

```
Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:276)
    OpenFileServlet.doGet(OpenFileServlet.java:17)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to use absolute path to file in these applications. You have to use paths relative to application install directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 8

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //...

        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\DevPrograms\\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\\webapps\\Report\\Logs"))) {
            List<byte[]> fileContents = paths
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(this::readAllBytes)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        //...

        return;

    }

    private byte[] readAllBytes(Path path) {
        try {
            return Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```